# XML/ATOM Getting error : response is not an Atom feed/entry

Tags: rest, nullpointerexception, xmlhttprequest, feed, atom-feed

I'm making a GET Request with 
`headers={'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml'}`

And I'm getting this as response:

```
result: 200 (OK) 
response headers: {'last-modified': 'Wed, 02 Oct 2013 22:17:45 GMT', 'content-length': '2328', 'etag': '1405175890', 'x-powered-by': 'Servlet/3.0', 'date': 'Wed, 02 Oct 2013 22:17:45 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/atom+xml'} 
response body:
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
.
.
.
.  
</content>
</entry>
</feed>
Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And I'm getting the error: "response is not an Atom feed/entry"
I tried different headers but i failed. How this issue can be solved ?
Code is written in Python and using '**requests**' Library.

Comment: There's some code missing here; what library or framework is producing that error?

Comment: @Joe Code is written in python and using 'requests' library.

Comment: I don't think that error is coming from `requests`. Show some code, and the line that's producing the error.

Comment: This issuewas resolved. There was a API Build issue from the Hardware end. Anyways, Thanks for looking into this problem.